# Python: sending mail via python creates unknown attachment

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I'm trying to send a mail + attachment (.pdf file) via python.
The mail is send but the attachment becomes an *unknown attachment* instead of being a .pdf file

My code looks like this:

```
import smtplib
import os
import ssl
import email

from email import encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

port = 465
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
subject = "An example of txt.file"
sender = "..."
receiver = "..."
password = "..."

message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = sender
message["To"] = receiver
message["Subject"] = subject

filename = '318.pdf'

attachment = open(filename, "rb")
part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
part.add_header('Content Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
encoders.encode_base64(part)
message.attach(part)

message.attach(part)

body = "This is an example  of how to send an email with an .pdf-attachment."
message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

text = message.as_string()

context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, text)

    print('Sent')
```

What is wrong with it or what do I have to do differently?

I've tried different file types, the .pdf file is in the python file directory,...

Comment: did that, still sends an unknown attachment

Comment: Im using MIMEApplication instead of MIMEBase

Comment: tried that, too... same problem for me

Comment: Also Im using MIMEMultipart('mixed')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
part.add_header('Content Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
```

But the 'filename' argument-name must be provided as a string and you also missed the hyphen in 'Content-Disposition'. Try

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename)
```

This should solve your issue. Just pointing out, you attached 'part' twice - on lines 20 and 22.

I think you might already be following [this](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) article. But if not, I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: That's the article I was following, you're correct.
If I change the code to:

part.add_header('Content Disposition', 'attachment', 'filename'=filename)

all I get is a SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment

Comment: I guess you mean .`add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename)`

Comment: Yes, it's "Content-Disposition", not "Content Disposition". You forgot the hyphen. Also, in the article you were following, they used an f-string to concatenate the second argument, which you didn't. So you could either accomplish that like @geckos showed or if your python version supports f-strings, you could use that too like they did in the article.
I apologize for not spotting that earlier, I have edited my answer. I hope it clears things up.